# How can I get the list of checked checkboxes using CGI.pm?

Tags: forms, perl, cgi

I have a form with multiple checkboxes. A user can select as many locations as he want, and I'm trying to save all of them in one array. I already tried the following options but doesn't work:

```
<input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="Location 1" name="location">  
<input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="Location 2" name="location"> 
<input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="Location 3" name="location"> 

my @location                   = $query->param('location');;
```

The above line of code gets all the location, but not separated by a comma, I also tried the following but don't get anything;

```
my $location       = join(",", @{ $query->param('location'); });
```

Comment: Have you tried using the brackets on the name? `name="location[]"` Otherwise the last element with the name will be used.

Comment: The code you posted doesn't even compile. Saying you "don't get anything" from it is a bit disingenuous, since you get error messages.

Comment: ALWAYS use `use strict; use warnings;`.

Comment: Finally, why didn't you mention that `my @location = $query->param('location');;` produces a warning (even without use strict; use warnings;`)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`$query->param('location')` in scalar context doesn't return a reference to an array, so your attempt to dereference it makes no sense, and Perl would have told you so had you been using `use strict; use warnings;` as you ALWAYS should.

As you noticed, `$query->param('location')` in list context returns all the values, so you want

```perl
join(",", $query->param('location'))
```

Of course, both your working snippet and this one produces the following warning:

> CGI::param called in list context from -e line 1, this can lead to vulnerabilities. See the warning in "Fetching the value or values of a single named parameter"

As the referenced section of the documentation states, you should be using `->multi_param` instead of `->param` in list context.

```perl
join(",", $query->multi_param('location'))
```

Comment: The only issues that I have using this option is that it only collect two values after that I get an error  "DBI quote: invalid number of arguments: got handle + 3, expected handle + between 1 and 2" any idea why

Comment: This Answer answers your Question. If you need help fixing the bug in your DBI code, feel free to ask a new Question. But do better this time; this question made a number of untrue claims. (See the comments to the answer.)